# How to setup an array property in a object model in angular 9

Tags: arrays, angular, model

In a model Game

```
export class Games{
    id: any;
    constructor(
      public name: string,
      public image: string,
      public releaseOn: string,// do it an array of releaseOn platform
      public releaseDate: string,
      public genre: string,// do it an array of genres
      public rating: number,
    ){}
  }
```

How to declare an array property in this model?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below.

```
export class Games{
  id: any;
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public image: string,
    public releaseOn: Array<ReleaseOn>,// do it an array of releaseOn platform
    public releaseDate: string,
    public genre: Array<Genres>,// do it an array of genres
    public rating: number,
  ){}
}

export class Genres {
  genre: string
}

export class ReleaseOn {
  releaseOn: string
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: how to get the object Games in the games.component.ts?     this.game = new Game('', '', [],  '', [], 1 );

Comment: I am working with an api. the object game has many arrays and sub arrays but I only need that properties maybe some more like next y prev for pagination but How I can know if an model in angular is being used by the component?